How can i open a vscode:// link directly to vscode instead of following the "open xdg-open" prompt?
I am trying to login to codeium from inside vscode (using the corresponding codeium extension), but during this process the site needs to open back a vscode:// url.
For some reason after confirming the "Open with xdg-open?" dialog, I get a window "No apps available".
Fortunately I can copy the link.
What I do not know is where I should paste that link in vscode in order to complete the process.

Vscode (or vscodium) can open that link with command like
/path/to/vscode --open-url [the url]

(Run that on terminal)

You can also register application to open that link automatically, by making .desktop file
example file in /usr/share/applications/code-url-handler.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Visual Studio Code - URL Handler
Comment=Code Editing. Redefined.
GenericName=Text Editor
Exec=/usr/share/code/code --open-url %U
Icon=vscode
Type=Application
NoDisplay=true
StartupNotify=true
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;Development;IDE;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/vscode;
Keywords=vscode;

Then run command
xdg-mime default code-url-handler.desktop x-scheme-handler/vscode

After that, whenever your web-browser tried to open that link, the browser will execute command like xdg-open vscode://some.url/, that will open your vscode with --open-url parameter that i mentioned above
